# PhantomJs and Seleno

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJs and Seleno to implement some UI tests. But the problem is whenever I'm trying to find an element on my page it throws an error. "Unknown Command"

code for initializing the servers are like this:

```
var projectPath =
               new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.Parent.GetDirectories("Foo")
                   .First()
                   .FullName;

        var loc = ProjectLocation.FromPath(projectPath);

        var service =PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

        service.Port= 123;
        var phantomJs = new PhantomJSDriver(service);

        Func<PhantomJSDriver> newFunc = () => phantomJs;

        var app = new WebApplication(loc, 123);
        Instance.Run(app, c => c
            .UsingLoggerFactory(new ConsoleFactory())
            .WithRemoteWebDriver(newFunc)
        );
```

it opens the iisexpress using port 123 and PhantomGhost is pointing to the same port.
and showing this error:

Unknown Command - Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","Cache-Control":"max-age=0","Connection":"keep-alive","Cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=a2umglrwcaquccg2rar0vzqa; .ASPXAUTH=7CBEDA8FC6170B15E116E77016D2136D4F58C8B73B0B2D54149B96847FE8A26E8D8FA24E41E5F0F0AFFE336D896B53C4628AB5B67B1960CB34727C85B6EF9720F7FF2A792BF1B5ECEECE5429DE212D8B7BA948978F302EF9B3A1040F05902AE92280FF8047D380583465D6CE6C6B103E5286F6FE37E75CFE22910E271BE2BEB4B552124B","Host":"localhost:12346","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"","directory":"/","path":"/","relative":"/","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/","queryKey":{},"chunks":[""]}}

I can browse to it using firefox as well it's showing the same error. and obviously selenium can't find the elements and it will show an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out if you upgrade the PhantomJS to the newest version it will solve the problem